# RegEx and validating telephone numbers

Tags: regex, validation, expression, match, regex-group

I'm learning RegEx, and I'm stuck in the following exercise:

I must match:

```
1 (555) 555-5555
5555555555
1 555-555-5555
555-555-5555
```

and not:

```
1 555)555-5555
(6505552368)
10 (757) 622-7382
555)-555-5555
```

My expression (not working) is:

```
/([0-9]? ?)?(([0-9]{3})|(\([0-9]{3}\)))( |\-)?\2\5?\2[0-9]/ig
```

Could you please help me? I can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: You can exercise here :  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber?

Comment: What is the difference between `1 (555) 555-5555` and `10 (757) 622-7382` ?

Comment: @CrescentFresh: thanks!! I'll try...

Comment: @k-five: thanks!! I'll try...

Comment: @Jan: Sorry, I didn't say the first number, if present, must be 1 followed by a space

Comment: @S4rg0n alright. you can also see there : https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/gla_42/ref/rregexp.html

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with:

```
^\d\ *(?:\(\d+\))?[- \d]+$
```

See a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9pP9/1).

**Broken down:**

```
^   - an anchor to bind the expression to the beginning of the line
\d  - one digit of 0-9
\ * - zero or more spaces
(?:\(\d+\))? - digits in parentheses, made optional
[- \d]+ - characters from the specified class
$ - bind the expression to the end
```

But quoting from the `regex` tag:

> Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions
>   with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable
>   programming language or tool.

Please update your question and apply the used programming language.

---

As pointed out by @Aminah, the given regex has flaws which can be avoided by using lookaheads, e.g.:

```
^(?!.*-{2,})\d\ *(?:\(\d+\))?[- \d]+$
```

The `(?!.*-{2,})` makes sure that there are no two consequent slashes allowd.

Comment: You are wrong. If you do it this way, how about `5555-----`?`

Comment: @AminahNuraini: You're right. I'd add a [negative lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9pP9/2) but the example was not in the original question.

Comment: He said telephone number. That's descriptive enough for that sample.

Comment: @AminahNuraini: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
/^(\d? ?)?(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d+$/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC0wA3/1)

### Explanation:

1. `^(\d? ?)?`: `^` to match the very beginning of the string. `\d` is equal to `[0-9]`
2. `(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))`: It's to match the second group where brackets are optional. You were right, but you put too many unnecessary parentheses.
3. `[ -]?`: It's equal to `( |-)?`
4. `\d+$`: `$` is for the end of the string.
5. `/gm`: `m` flag is for multiple lines

Comment: Where is the case insensitive modifier needed with numbers?

Comment: We don't need it, but I forgot to delete it from the original regex the asker wrote

Comment: @AminahNuraini: Thank you!!! I tried to repeat a capturing group 555 = ([0-9]{3}) = group #3 and ( |\-) = #5 but it didn't work. Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: it should be group 2. You count it wrong.

Comment: I meant my (wrong) example

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but it's confusing for me too

Answer (score 1):

Ok this one is bit tricky, to test actually.

Here you go:

```
^(\d\s?(?:\(\d{3}\))?\s?[\d|\-]{8,12})$
```

This one catches the full numbers only and returns the complete number, not the partials like others mentioned in other answers.

Test here:

https://regex101.com/r/hI5vT2/2